# Getting data from aspx website using Python/R

Tags: python, r

Hi I want to get all food nutrition information on this website: https://focos.hpb.gov.sg/eservices/ENCF/foodsearch.aspx

Users will have to select `Food Group` and/or `Nutrient`, then select the items (maximum 3 items) and press confirm to skip to details page.
[image]

After that the link will change to https://focos.hpb.gov.sg/eservices/ENCF/FoodAnalysis.aspx?p=2 (same for all result)

Result of each food shown as

[image]

I would like to able to extract the information for all the food item as below:

| Food Name | Food Group | Food Sub Group | Description | Energy (kcal) | Protein (g) | Total fat (g) | Saturated fat (g) | Dietary fibre (g) | Carbohydrate (g) | Cholesterol (mg) | Sodium (mg) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Apple Juice | BEVERAGES | Non-alcoholic beverages | 100%, Marigold | 50 kcal | NA | NA | NA | 0.8 g | 12 g | NA | 1 mg |

I have tried

```py
import requests

url = "http://www.....aspx?download=1"

file_name = "Data.csv"
u = requests.get(url)

file_size = int(u.headers['content-length'])
print "Downloading: %s Bytes: %s" % (file_name, file_size)

with open(file_name, 'wb') as f:
    for chunk in u.iter_content(chunk_size=1024): 
        if chunk: # filter out keep-alive new chunks
            f.write(chunk)
            f.flush()
f.close()
```

but my output is

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" > <head><link href="../App_Themes/Intranet/Style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" /> <!-- Google tag (gtag.js) --> <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-4130C60GP2"></script> <script> window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || []; function gtag() { dataLayer.push(arguments); } gtag('js' gtag('config' </script><title> "   Energy & Nutrient Composition Search" </title> <script nonce="FOCOS2023"  language="JavaScript" src='../common/CommonJS.js'></script> <script nonce="FOCOS2023"  type="text/javascript" src='../highslide/highslide-full.js'></script> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../highslide/highslide.css" /> <script nonce="FOCOS2023"  type="text/javascript"> hs.graphicsDir = '../highslide/graphics/'; hs.outlineType = 'rounded-white'; hs.wrapperClassName = 'draggable-header';
```